# jhipster run embedded jar with prod profile - issue with liquibase

Tags: liquibase, jhipster

I have packaged my app with : 
mvn -Pprod package

Then I ran

```
java -jar myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
```

it works fine.
But if I run :

```
java -jar myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war --spring.profiles.active=prod
```

I am getting this error:

```
[ERROR] org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.ServletContextInitializerLifecycleListener - Error starting Tomcat context: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException
[WARN] org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:124) [spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:474) ~[spring-context-4.1.3.RELEASE.jar!/:4.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109) [spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691) [spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321) [spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at com.myapp.Application.main(Application.java:57) [classes!/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_25]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53) [bioandbio-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_25]
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:97) ~[spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:74) ~[spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:374) ~[spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:150) ~[spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:148) [spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:121) [spring-boot-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.2.0.RELEASE]
    ... 11 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.setFilterChainProxySecurityConfigurer(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor,java.util.List) throws java.lang.Exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService com.myapp.config.SecurityConfiguration.userDetailsService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userDetailsService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.myapp.repository.UserRepository com.myapp.security.UserDetailsService.userRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#1f1288f5' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#1f1288f5': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [com/myapp/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:
     1 change sets check sum
          classpath:config/liquibase/changelog/00000000000000_initial_schema.xml::00000000000001::jhipster is now: 7:788e6cd59e4764c45e1b83437356e748
```

I don't understand why prod profile causes this issue.
If someone knows what's wrong here

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Reading all the way to the bottom of the stack trace, I see that the root cause is a liquibase checksum validation failure. I'm not sure how familiar you are with liquibase, but it is a tool that is embedded inside jhipster that is used to manage database schema changes as your objects change. What liquibase does is use an XML format to describe the database schema as a series of 'changesets'. When liquibase deploys a changeset (i.e. a changeset that says 'changeset with id "CreateTableFoo" is "create table foo with columns bar baz etc") is that it actually creates the table, and then it also adds a row to a table called 'databasechangelog' that records that the changeset "CreateTableFoo" was successfully applied at such and such a time, and the checksum of that changeset was some value. Now, if you come along and change the changeset xml file so that the changeset "CreateTableFoo" instead creates a table with a different name or different columns, then the checksum calculated for that changeset also changes, so when you try to update the schema liquibase says "Wait! Something wrong!"

So that is what is happening here.

`Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [com/myapp/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:
     1 change sets check sum
          classpath:config/liquibase/changelog/00000000000000_initial_schema.xml::00000000000001::jhipster is now: 7:788e6cd59e4764c45e1b83437356e748`

What this indicates is that the prod database already has had a liquibase update run on it to populate the schema, but that the changeset has changed since that initial deploy. I am not familiar with how jhipster uses liquibase, so you would need to look at the file `classpath:config/liquibase/changelog/00000000000000_initial_schema.xml` to see what database schema it is trying to set up, and compare that to the schema that is actually in place in production.

Now that things are out of sync, you'll have to figure out a way to get them back in sync, which is more complicated than can be answered here and depends greatly on what the differences between the changelog and the production schema are.

Comment: Thanks for this very complete answer and for the time you spent to explain everything. Now it's very clear in my mind.

Comment: This happens if a changelog file was edited after it had already been applied to the database. The validation error detects is because the file is different to when it was applied. The correct way to apply changes to the database is to add a new changelog file.