# Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource ... /config/DatabaseConfiguration.class

Tags: java, jhipster, liquibase

I have this annoying error when starting Embedded Tomcat on my jHipster Project. Spent a lot of time trying to resolve it but can't figure out why it's happening. It started happening after updating project from main rep but I also implemented Custom Repository.

**Stack Trace:**

```
    DEBUG] uk.co.
config.DatabaseConfiguration - Configuring Liquibase
[WARN] org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered d
uring context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path
 resource [uk/co/inspiresoft/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:
     1 change sets check sum
          classpath:config/liquibase/changelog/00000000000000_initial_schema.xml::00000000000001::jhipster is now: 7:bde
7b076d47aefe8278d126cde26b172

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireC
apableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCap
ableBeanFactory.java:539) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapab
leBeanFactory.java:476) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303) ~[spr
ing-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegis
try.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299) ~[sprin
g-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) ~[spring-
beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListable
BeanFactory.java:755) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplic
ationContext.java:757) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480) ~
[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext
.java:118) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar
:1.2.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320) [spring-boot-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2
.3.RELEASE]
        at uk.co.Application.main(Application.java:59) [classes/:na]
Caused by: liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:
     1 change sets check sum
          classpath:config/liquibase/changelog/00000000000000_initial_schema.xml::00000000000001::jhipster is now: 7:bde
7b076d47aefe8278d126cde26b172

        at liquibase.changelog.DatabaseChangeLog.validate(DatabaseChangeLog.java:196) ~[liquibase-core-3.3.2.jar:na]
        at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:196) ~[liquibase-core-3.3.2.jar:na]
        at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:353) ~[liquibase-core-3.3.2.j
ar:na]
        at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:317) ~[liquibase-core-3.
3.2.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowi
reCapableBeanFactory.java:1633) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireC
apableBeanFactory.java:1570) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
        ... 13 common frames omitted
[INFO] uk.co.config.CacheConfiguration - Closing Cache Manager
[INFO] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService - [192.168.1.48]:5701 [dev] [3.4] Address[192.168.1.48]:5701 is SHUTTING_DOWN
```

This is my **DatabaseConfiguration.class**

```
    import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnMissingClass;
import org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedPropertyResolver;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException;
import org.springframework.context.EnvironmentAware;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaAuditing;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import com.codahale.metrics.MetricRegistry;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.hibernate4.Hibernate4Module;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig;
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass=uk.co.repository.IRepositoryFactoryBean.class, basePackages={"uk.co.repository"})
@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "springSecurityAuditorAware")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DatabaseConfiguration implements EnvironmentAware {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DatabaseConfiguration.class);

    private RelaxedPropertyResolver propertyResolver;

    private Environment env;

    @Autowired(required = false)
    private MetricRegistry metricRegistry;

    @Override
    public void setEnvironment(Environment env) {
        this.env = env;
        this.propertyResolver = new RelaxedPropertyResolver(env, "spring.datasource.");
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    @ConditionalOnMissingClass(name = "uk.co.config.HerokuDatabaseConfiguration")
    @Profile("!" + Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_CLOUD)
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        log.debug("Configuring Datasource");
        if (propertyResolver.getProperty("url") == null && propertyResolver.getProperty("databaseName") == null) {
            log.error("Your database connection pool configuration is incorrect! The application" +
                    "cannot start. Please check your Spring profile, current profiles are: {}",
                    Arrays.toString(env.getActiveProfiles()));

            throw new ApplicationContextException("Database connection pool is not configured correctly");
        }
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setDataSourceClassName(propertyResolver.getProperty("dataSourceClassName"));
        if (propertyResolver.getProperty("url") == null || "".equals(propertyResolver.getProperty("url"))) {
            config.addDataSourceProperty("databaseName", propertyResolver.getProperty("databaseName"));
            config.addDataSourceProperty("serverName", propertyResolver.getProperty("serverName"));
        } else {
            config.addDataSourceProperty("url", propertyResolver.getProperty("url"));
        }
        config.addDataSourceProperty("user", propertyResolver.getProperty("username"));
        config.addDataSourceProperty("password", propertyResolver.getProperty("password"));

        if (metricRegistry != null) {
            config.setMetricRegistry(metricRegistry);
        }
        return new HikariDataSource(config);
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringLiquibase liquibase(DataSource dataSource) {
        SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
        liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
        liquibase.setChangeLog("classpath:config/liquibase/master.xml");
        liquibase.setContexts("development, production");
        if (env.acceptsProfiles(Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_FAST)) {
            if ("org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource".equals(propertyResolver.getProperty("dataSourceClassName"))) {
                liquibase.setShouldRun(true);
                log.warn("Using '{}' profile with H2 database in memory is not optimal, you should consider switching to" +
                    " MySQL or Postgresql to avoid rebuilding your database upon each start.", Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_FAST);
            } else {
                liquibase.setShouldRun(false);
            }
        } else {
            log.debug("Configuring Liquibase");
        }
        return liquibase;
    }

    @Bean
    public Hibernate4Module hibernate4Module() {
        return new Hibernate4Module();
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {

      HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
      vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);

      LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
      factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
      factory.setPackagesToScan("uk.co.repository");
      factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
      factory.afterPropertiesSet();

      return factory.getObject();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the code for your `SpringLiquibase` class.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment, I actually now found the reason for this - the value in the field databasechangelog.md5sum for script 00000000000000_initial_schema.xml::00000000000001 which is in database is different than the one that jHipster is generating upon update to new version. Because of this clash, liquidbase was complaining, even though the script itself hasn't been changed. I now updated the field value in database to match what liquidbase is trying to  enter and it all worked, validation passed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28427950/jhipster-run-embedded-jar-with-prod-profile-issue-with-liquibase has good explanation of liquidbase check.

Comment: You have a liquibase validation issue, check the following post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9995747/liquibase-checksum-validation-error-without-any-changes

Comment: @ivan, If you have found a solution to your own problem, you should add it as a solution and accept it.  This way other people can clearly see the solution instead of having to find it in comments.  Comments cannot be verified as correct by the community.

Answer (score 10):

It is a known fact that **Liquibase** writes all changelogs into a table named as **databasechangelog** in your database as:

> The root of all Liquibase changes is the databaseChangeLog file.

When I had the similar error occuring, I solved it manually by altering the checksum value in the **databasechangelog** table in my database. You can solve it by running the following SQL query in your database:

```
UPDATE `databasechangelog` SET `MD5SUM`=`7:bde7b076d47aefe8278d126cde26b172` WHERE `ID`=`00000000000001`;
```

**ANOTHER WORKAROUND**

Truncate the `databasechangelog` table. Add **no-liquibase** in appropriate place in the **pom.xml** file as below:

```
<properties>
    <spring.profiles.active>local,no-liquibase</spring.profiles.active>
</properties>
```

And then run **mvn** (or **mvnw**, as per your project settings) and the application will be launched successfully!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. My solution is this way:


Open ;

*Database Tables (mySql or postgresql or another)

*databasechangeloglock Table


Change;

*Locked=false

I reached the solution in this way. I hope it solves your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem many times, the fastest way for me was to delete all the tables with records that were generated, and rerun the application.

Comment: can't do that in production

Answer (score 1):

I use rancher v1 and I needed to run this inside the mysql database:

`DELETE FROM DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK where ID = 1;`

Comment: You should include some documentation about what that code is supposed to do, and how it solves the asked problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was because the file did not load properly.

I used `includeAll` to show `liquibase` where the include file is.

## db.changelog-master.yaml

```
databaseChangeLog:
 - includeAll:
    path: classpath*:db/changelog/changes/
 - include:
    file: db/changelog/changes/a.yaml
```

### reference

[Liquibase and Spring Boot | Object Partners](https://objectpartners.com/2018/05/09/liquibase-and-spring-boot/)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error running flowable-admin which also uses liquibase with spring

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in org.flowable.admin.conf.DatabaseConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [liquibase.Liquibase]: Factory method 'liquibase' threw exception; nested exception is or
g.flowable.app.service.exception.InternalServerErrorException: Error creating liquibase database
       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:587)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1250)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(
```

I also solved this using the suggestion above by modifying the **databasechangeloglock** table which was set to **true**, apparently due to an error during application of changes to **databasechanglog** which had terminated badly.  Setting it to **false** solved this issue and the flowable-admin started up fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, for the delete the table and re run the application or update the table for the id showing in the logs:

Update "table_Name" set column_Name = 'changeValueGivenInTheLog (after was)' where id = "valueGivenInTheLog (dbchangeLog::**idValue**)"