# Creating multiple beans by a list in properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, liquibase

Basically, I would like to create beans by a list in my application.yml file.

I have to use multiple Liquibase changelog files within my Spring Boot application. Sadly, I can't do it in spring boot's configuration and I cannot put these files into one file, because the number of changelog files is always changing. Not an ideal situation but I cannot do anything against it now.
So, I figured out that defining Liquibase beans can help me out. Changelog files are getting used in the right order. But I want to add the files in the `application.yml` file.

```yaml
myconfig:
  - pathToChangeLogFile_1
  - pathToChangeLogFile_2
  - pathToChangeLogFile_3
```

```java
import java.sql.DataSource;
import liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase;

@Configuration
class LiquibaseConfiguration {
    
    @Bean
    public SpringLiquibase firstLiquibase(Datasource dataSource) {
        SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibse();
        liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
        // ...
        // other method calls
        liquibase.setChangeLog("pathToChangeLogFile_1");
        return liquibase;
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("firstLiquibase")
    public SpringLiquibase secondLiquibase(Datasource dataSource) {
        SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibse();
        liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
        // ...
        // other method calls
        liquibase.setChangeLog("pathToChangeLogFile_2");
        return liquibase;
    }

    // Other beans and etc.
}
```

I don't want to rewrite my code every time a file is getting added. How would I create beans in spring by the application property config (list)? I thought of some kind of bean factory but I don't know how should I make sure my bean is getting the `DataSource` there which is pretty straightforward with bean definition.
I looked at `ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar`, `EnvironmentAware`, `BeanFactoryAware` interfaces but I can't tell if I am on the good track.

Answer (score 0):

This answer was posted previously: [Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource ... /config/DatabaseConfiguration.class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29711327/error-creating-bean-with-name-liquibase-defined-in-class-path-resource-co)

> I had the same problem. My solution is this way:
>
> ```
>      Open ;
>      *Database Tables (mySql or postgresql or another)
>      *databasechangeloglock Table
>
>      Change;
>      *Locked=false
> ```
>
> I reached the solution in this way. I hope it solves your problem.